# Should Domain Controller Sync the time if there is time difference between locations

Tags: domain-controller, ntp, time-synchronization

I have the Primary DC in Toronto syncing time as NTP. I have a read-only DC in Tokyo, the time sync is NT5DS, so all my servers, PCs on remote site got wrong time now. Do I have to set this read-only DC to sync the time to outside or internally?

Comment: Something is wrong here, but not due to different time zones. Windows stores time in UTC. When a domain member syncs with the domain hierarchy it receives time information as unadjusted UTC and then adjusts it for the local timezone. The fact that you have domain members in different time zones should not be causing this problem. Do you have all of the domain members set to the correct local timezone? Also, when you say the have the wrong time what do you mean exactly? They have the wrong time based on their time zone or they have the wrong time as in their clocks are either fast or slow?

Comment: Not only time is wrong but Year, month are all wrong. I dont need to setup time zone on each sever or PC, it should receive the correct time/date when they joining to the domain controlled by policy.

Comment: All good now. Simply run "net time \\dc /set /y"   Thanks